# My Application is not uploading data on server

Tags: android, mysql

I am trying to upload data on my online server through android app, all the php code and databases are tested they are ok but the android app is not uploading data in Php mysql database.
SendActivity is taking Edittext code and then after converting into string it is sent into BackgroundTask class and through backgrorund task it is uploaded on server which is not happening right now.

**SendActivity.java**

```
public void sendbtn(View view)
{
    u_name = name.getText().toString();
    u_email = email.getText().toString();
    u_city = city.getText().toString();
    u_address = address.getText().toString();
    u_phone= city.getText().toString();
    u_altEmail = altEmail.getText().toString();
    String basit = "Basit";
    //String method = "register";
    BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
    backgroundTask.execute(basit,basit,basit,basit,basit,basit,basit,basit);
    finish();

}
```

**BackgroundTask.java**

```
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
{
    String add_info_url;
    private Context context;
    //in constructor:
    public BackgroundTask(Context context){
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        add_info_url = "http://ezprint.com.pk/add_info.php";
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args)
    {
        String name = args[0];
        String email = args[1];
        String phone = args[2];
        String altaddress = args[3];
        String city = args[4];
        String address = args[5];
        String imgCount = args[6];
        String imagesize = args[7];
        try {
            URL url = new URL(add_info_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection =(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter buffer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS , "UTF-8"));
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("name" , "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(name , "UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("email" , "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(email , "UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("city" , "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(city , "UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("address" , "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(address , "UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("altaddress" , "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(altaddress , "UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("phone" , "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(phone , "UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("images" , "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(imgCount , "UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("imagesize" , "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(imagesize , "UTF-8");
            buffer.write(data);
            buffer.flush();
            buffer.close();
            OS.close();
            InputStream is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            is.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return "Order is placed successfully";

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(context,result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**Error log**

```
12-01 19:31:28.450 9688-12744/org.app.ezprints.photoshopX I/System.out: [socket][0] connection ezprint.com.pk/104.223.95.197:80;LocalPort=36287(0)
```

12-01 19:31:28.450 9688-12744/org.app.ezprints.photoshopX I/System.out: [CDS]connect[ezprint.com.pk/104.223.95.197:80]
12-01 19:31:28.730 9688-12744/org.app.ezprints.photoshopX I/System.out: [CDS]port[36287]
12-01 19:31:28.730 9688-12744/org.app.ezprints.photoshopX I/System.out: [socket][/192.168.0.107:36287] connected
12-01 19:31:28.730 9688-12744/org.app.ezprints.photoshopX I/System.out: [CDS]rx timeout:0
12-01 19:31:29.130 9688-12744/org.app.ezprints.photoshopX I/System.out: [CDS]rx timeout:100
12-01 19:31:29.130 9688-12744/org.app.ezprints.photoshopX I/System.out: [CDS]rx timeout:100
12-01 19:31:29.130 9688-12744/org.app.ezprints.photoshopX I/System.out: [CDS]rx timeout:100
12-01 19:31:29.130 9688-12744/org.app.ezprints.photoshopX I/System.out: [CDS]rx timeout:0

Comment: share your error log

Comment: See this error log @MiteshVanaliya

Comment: it is timeout, may be there is no network connection in your device/emulator, make sure to check it for example by using device browser

Comment: @hakim I have checked my internet is working perfectly

Answer (score 4):

You set `httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");` but you want to upload some data.

So you should change your request method to `POST`.

Comment: I am glad to have helped you ;)
If you can, please mark this answer as accepted and upvote it!

Answer (score 0):

make sure to add internet permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```